# The Format of Mutation Generation of PIT Tool

Tags: java, testing, regression-testing, mutation-testing, pitest

I am interested in mutation testing and I want to generate faults in code with mutation testing tools and I found PIT.
Besides I am reading a paper about regression testing and it gave the experimental data on its site. On of the data is the output of PIT which is the faults in this format:

```
com.notnoop.apns.PayloadBuilder:<init>:()V:55:12:0
```

or

```
com.notnoop.apns.PayloadBuilder:insertCustomAlert:()V:377:14:0
```

and etc

But I don't understand the format of the output and what it is.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output is not from PIT itself, it has been created by the author of the paper you are reading.

The first section is the method signature, the numbers may be some combination of line, block and columns within the source file. You will need to either contact the authors of the paper to find out or reverse engineer the scheme from further examples.